# Why does window.scrollTo action only fire on initial page load?

Tags: reactjs

So I want a scroll action to take place every time my component is called, which it does if I load the component directly. But if I navigate to the component from elsewhere, then the scroll process does not work. Why?

```
const scrollToRef = (ref) => window.scrollTo(0, ref.current.offsetTop);

const OrderList = props => {
  const topRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    scrollToRef(topRef);
  },[]);

  return (
    <>
    <div style={{height:1500}} />
    <div ref={topRef} id="top">I wanna see.</div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Are you using `react-router-dom` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably race condition, the effect is called on component initialization, the ref is set later. A better approach would be:

`const scrollToComp = el => el && window.scrollTo(0, el.offsetTop);`

and then

`<div ref={scrollToComp}>...</div>`

Answer (score 0):

If you pass an empty array to `useEffect` as a second argument, it won't track any variables from the component and fire the function inside it only once.

More info in the [official React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects).

Answer (score 0):

> But if I navigate to the component from elsewhere, then the scroll process does not work. Why?

Because the navigation isn't rerendering the component.

You need to pass some `prop` of the navigation on the `useEffect` so when the navigation change the page, it runs the effect again.

Please especify what navigation you are using.